# Change the color of multiple cells with one mouse click in Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am using Swing to create a game that has a 10 by 10 grid of cells. The color of each cell can be changed by a mouse click. Here are two classes that work together to accomplish this:

```
 public class Grid extends Battle {
     public Grid(String name) {
         super();

     }

     @Override
     protected JPanel getCell()
     {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.setBackground(Color.black);
         panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 1));
         panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));

               panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()   {
             public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
             {
                panel.setBackground(Color.green);
             }
         });

         return panel;
     }
     }

          public abstract class Battle extends JPanel {
     public BattleGrid() {
         this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
         JPanel self = new JPanel();
         self.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,10));
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
             for(int j =0; j < 10; j++) {
             JPanel panel = getCell();
             self.add(panel); 
             }
         }
         this.add(self);
     }

     protected abstract JPanel getCell();
 }
```

The code works for any one particular cell. My question is, how can I change the color of multiple cells in the grid with ONE mouse click? For example, when you click on the grid you change the color of two cells: the one you click on AND the one that is, say, immediately to the right of it? Thank you in advance!

Edit: for those who run into a similar problem - I found super similar solution. Simply increase the dimension of the JPanel being clicked on and return in. For example, the dimension of my JPanel is 20 by 20. So if you want to color 2 cells with one click - the one being clicked and the one to the right - all you have to do is:
           panel.setSize(new Dimension(40,20));

Comment: You need to separate the state management into another class, i.e. a model, which maintains information about what is selected (and possibly information which can be used to determine the color). This would then provide a observer pattern, which could be used to notify interested parties of changes to the state of the model. When you click a single cell, you notify the model of the change for that cell, the model make decisions about how to handle that change and generates appropriate notifications - this is the bases of a MVC

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, but given the fact that we have just started learning swing and handling action listeners I am fairly certain the solution should not be this complex. Is there a way to handle this somehow from inside the for-loop? Write a new method?

Comment: This is not complex, this is basically the same concept that Swing uses and most modern development is based on.  It's among a series of core fundamental software development building blocks, which, if you take the time to learn, can be used to solve a number of problems easily and efficiently

Comment: Tried your solution - NPE in the Cell class on the line model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()

Comment: Then you must be passing a `null` value for the model to the `Cell` class

Comment: I simply copied and pasted your code, made some import statements to compile. Other than that, haven't changed anything.

Comment: The Grid class requires you to pass an instance of a GridModel as part of the constructor. Since you failed to give a runnable example, I just hobbled an example of the idea together

Comment: Do I need to pass new GridModel() from Grid constructor to Cell constructor? If so, how do I pass something from a constructor into another constructor of a different class?

Comment: Yes - [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think this link has information about passing arguments from a constructor to another constructor of a different class.

Comment: It's the same basic concept as passing information via a method to another method

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Even if I did, your code looks way too complex and I don't think would be acceptable for our class level especially considering that this is only a small part of what the program is supposed to do. I will try to find a simpler solution. Again, thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by decoupling the state management from the rest of the code.  This should be maintained in some kind of model, which has no concept of the UI, nor should it care, it simply managers the state and makes appropriate decisions about what should be done as that state is changed.

The model would provide an observer pattern implementation, which allow it to generate events when the state is changed, allowing interested parties know when the state has changed, so they can respond to it.

```
public enum CellState {
    EMPTY, SELECTED
}

public class GridModel {

    private Set<ChangeListener> listeners;

    private CellState[][] grid;

    public GridModel() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>(25);
        grid = new CellState[10][10];
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < grid[col].length; row++) {
                grid[col][row] = CellState.EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setCellState(CellState state, int x, int y) {
        grid[x][y] = state;
    }

    public CellState getCellStateAt(int x, int y) {
        return grid[x][y];
    }

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I'd create a dedicated `Cell` component which would be responsible for the management of a single cell.  This would provide a visual representation of a cell within the model and coordinate interaction between the user and the model.

```
public class Cell extends JPanel {

    private GridModel model;

    public Cell(GridModel model, int x, int y) {
        this.model = model;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 1));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                getModel().setCellState(CellState.SELECTED, x, y);
            }
        });

        model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                switch (getModel().getCellStateAt(x, y)) {
                    case SELECTED:
                        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        break;
                    case EMPTY:
                        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(20, 20);
    }

    public GridModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

And then, your `Grid` class would create an instance of this `Cell` as required

```
public class Grid extends Battle {

    private GridModel model;

    public Grid(String name, GridModel model) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
    }

    public GridModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected JPanel getCell(int x, int y) {
        return new Cell(getModel(), x, y);
    }
}
```

This is only a proof of concept and your requirements may be more complex then I've generally presented, by the basic concept of decoupled state manager (model) and notification system (observer pattern) and the key elements to your solution.

This moves you closer to a Model-View-Controller paradigm, allow appropriate separation of various responsibilities with the system